# uitableview questions

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

i try to this condition but don't work. If the senderlabel = key@"sender" use the green.png or the grey.png for every rows.

```
    if (senderLabel.text = [tempMsg objectForKey:@"sender"]) 
    {
        [cell.msgText setText:[tempMsg objectForKey:@"message"]];

        [messTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

        //[cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, size.width, size.height)];
        [cell.msgText setFrame:CGRectMake(15,3, size.width, result)]; 




        UIImage* balloon = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"grey.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24  topCapHeight:15];
        UIImageView *newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, size.width+10, result+10)];
        UIView *newView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

        [newImage setImage:balloon];
        [newView addSubview:newImage];
        [cell setBackgroundView:newView];

    }else {
        [cell.msgText setText:[tempMsg objectForKey:@"message"]];

        [messTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

        //[cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, size.width, size.height)];
        [cell.msgText setFrame:CGRectMake(15,3, size.width, result)]; //propriété du texte


        UIImage* balloon = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24  topCapHeight:15];
        UIImageView *newImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, size.width+10, result+10)];
        UIView *newView =[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

        [newImage setImage:balloon];
        [newView addSubview:newImage];
        [cell setBackgroundView:newView];

    }



    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if (senderLabel.text = [tempMsg objectForKey:@"sender"]) is not correct.  You need to use isEqual in your comparison.

```
if ([senderLabel.text isEqual:[tempMsg objectForKey:@"sender"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, here

```
if (senderLabel.text = [tempMsg objectForKey:@"sender"])
```

you are making an assignment, not a comparison, comparing would be

```
if (senderLabel.text == [tempMsg objectForKey:@"sender"])
```

However, that would compare if it's the exact same object in memory, which is probably not what you want, if you want to check if the string has the same text, you have to use

```
[string isEqualToString:anotherString]
```

Comment: thx but all my data use green. in every rows i have different datas

Comment: i think i have to use indexPath.row but how?

Comment: You could subclass UITableViewCell and add your own background there, it'd be easier and faster. Remember to override setFrame: to change the size of the background.

Answer (score 0):

To get indexpath you can use like this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

and for comparison:

```
if ([string compare:anotherString] == NSOrderedSame)
```